# how to left and right click on MSI Cyborg 15

Tags: laptop, mouse, windows-11, gaming

I've just recently bought the MSI Cyborg 15 gaming laptop. The first game I've tried to play is GTA V, and unless im doing something wrong, theres a problem. As far as I can tell, the mousepad on this laptop only has one button for the whole pad, but uses the trackpad to see which side your finger is on and then left or right clicks accordingly. Now, playing GTA V PC, you hold right click to aim a gun and then tap the left click to fire. Unfortunatly, as far as I can tell, with this mousepad configuration, there is now way to left and right click at the same time. I will be using proper soon anyway, but as I bought this laptop yesterday, I havent got one yet and so im just wondering, am I doing something wrong? is there anther way to do it? or is it just a design flaw.

Comment: A touchpad isn't suitable to play GTA.